# Running websocket server with stomp

Tags: websocket, jrubyonrails, hornetq, stomp, torquebox

I have torquebox installed in my jruby on Rails application. And I am experimenting with using stomp + websockets. But I can't tell if the websocket server is even running? I am booting up torquebox in my console with: `sudo torquebox run --clustered -b my.ip.address`

I keep going through the output from torquebox booting up and the only relevant output I am seeing is this:

`[org.torquebox.stomp.as] Initializing TorqueBox STOMP Subsystem`

and

`[org.projectodd.polyglot.stomp.as] Initializing Polyglot STOMP Subsystem`

I don't see anything referencing port 8675, which according to the docs is the port it is supposed to run on. I tried telnet as well and received a 'connection refused' message.

Any help or references would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the dumb question. I just had a typo in my torquebox.yml file. I can now see the output in the bootup that specifies the websocket server is up and I can successfully telnet in.